# Google maps, geoxml3, clear before AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, geoxml3

I use geoXML to add many polygons and points to my map. I have KML file that is generated dynamically based on changes in associated form.

```
...
function xmldata(center,zoom,objects) {                     
var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, zoom: false});
myParser.parse('http://localhost/private/infofly/misc/nearest.php?zoom=' + zoom + '&coordinates=' + center + '&' + objects + '');
}
...
```

It works great, but old KML records remain in the map after update. How can i clean objects in map before every new AJAX call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should hide all the objects from the previous version:

```
var myParser=null;  // global myParser reference (outside of any function)
function xmldata(center,zoom,objects) {                     
  if (myParser) myParser.hideDocument();
  myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, zoom: false});
  myParser.parse('http://localhost/private/infofly/misc/nearest.php?zoom=' + zoom + '&coordinates=' + center + '&' + objects + '');
}
```

Comment: Returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hideDocument' of null

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault, myParser.hideDocument(); must be call after some geoXML and before next AJAX call. Your solution works, thank you.

Comment: Oops, forgot about the first call, only call .hideDocument if myParser is not null.